# $.ajax error callback being called instead of success

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making ajax get request. I am getting a 200 Ok response from the server. However the error callback is being called instead of success callback.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'http://10.221.48.168/Publish/?fileId=1026',
    cache: false,
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

**Fiddler** 
*Request*

```
GET http://10.221.48.168/Publish/?fileId=1026&_=1404324352691 HTTP/1.1    
Referer: http://localhost:60391/TntBulkUpload/Index    
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US    
Origin: http://localhost:60391    
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate    
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0)    
Host: 10.221.48.168    
DNT: 1    
Connection: Keep-Alive    
Pragma: no-cache
```

*Response:*

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK    
Date: Wed, 02 Jul 2014 11:05:16 -0700    
Server: Mule Core/3.5.0    
X-MULE_SESSION: gAJeHB4    
X-MULE_ENCODING: UTF-8    
Content-Type: text/plain    
Content-Length: 37    
Connection: close    

/Publish/?fileId=1026&_=1404324352691
```

Edit:**Browser Console Errors:**

```
SEC7118: XMLHttpRequest for http://10.221.48.168/Publish/?fileId=1026&_=1404325311488 required Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS). 
SEC7120: Origin http://localhost:60391 not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. 
SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.
```

Comment: the CORS header is missing. you also forgot to mention the red error in your javascript console related to the same origin policy.

Comment: Added the error messages from the browser console.

Comment: You aren't adhering to the same origin policy. Typically all you have to change to make it work would be modify `10.221.48.168` server to return proper CORS headers. A few examples can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to add an entry to your Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on the application that returns success or error (10.221.48.168/Publish/?fileId=1026&_=1404324352691).

I'm not sure what language that application is using but if you're using ASP.NET, see this great reference here to enable CORS: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors